# ASP.net Request Validator Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am making first website in asp.net 
I am using Required Field Validator with my textbox.but its giving following exception

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping
>   for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named
>   jquery(case-sensitive).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: WebForms
>   UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for
>   'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named
>   jquery(case-sensitive).

Comment: Refer this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a

Comment: In your script folder do you have jquery.validate.unobtrusive,jquery.validate,jquery.unobtrusive-ajax js files?

Comment: You should post your code for this type of error, Also go through [How to ask good question on stack](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it will help you in the future

Comment: @Sain Pradeep Your link was good but still i am facing problem

Comment: @SainPradeep where is Global.asax file?

Comment: <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtusername" ErrorMessage="User Name is Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: If not then please add. Please refer this http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/how-to-add-globalasaxcs-file-in-aspnet.html